# How to check for repeated value in array in previous position?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check for the previous values in the array to see if it is repeated and if so, end the function and keep on the next non repeated value.
say you have

```
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim weeks(1 To lRow - 1)

    For i = 2 To lRow
        weeks(i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Sheet1.Cells(i, "C"), vbMonday)
        'MsgBox lRow
    Next i
```

so the vector "weeks" have (15,4,8,15,15,4,16)

```
lRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To sizeOf(weeks) 
    addHours= 0
    For j = 2 To lRow
        If WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, "B"), vbMonday) = weeks(i) Then
            addHours= addHours+ Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, "C").Value
            Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, "F") = addHours

        End If
    Next j
    addHours= 0
Next i
WeekHours = addHours
```

when the code above hits "weeks(3)" it should skip it and check if the next is repeated and keep skiping, if not then make the addition.

Any help would be great

Comment: use a dictionary (you will need to add the scripting reference library). check each element of your array (dictionary.exists(element)). If it doesn't, add it (dictionary.add(element)). If it does, it is a repeated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary instead of an array. There are no duplicate keys in a dictionary.

```
Dim weeks as object, k as variant

lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
set weeks = createobject("scripting.dictionary")

For i = 2 To lRow
    weeks.Item(WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Sheet1.Cells(i, "C"), vbMonday)) = vbnullstring
Next i

for each k in weeks.keys
    debug.print k
next k
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will check it out

Comment: How can I get the size of that object weeks?

Comment: `weeks.count` produces the count. Note that I amended the For Next that iterates through the dictionary keys.

Comment: btw, if you just want to transfer the dictionary keys to a regular variant array then `arr = weeks.keys`.